# A non metric first countable topological space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, first-countable

Every metric space is first countable, but what about the converse? Does it always hold? If not, can anyone give a counterexample?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29) is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ (and so first countable) but is not metrizable.

Less exotically, the [lower limit topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) on $\mathbb R$ is also first countable but not metrizable.

Answer (score 5):

The converse is false. Take the Sierpinski space $X = \{0,1\}$ with topology given by $\tau = \{ \varnothing, \{0\}, \{0,1\}  \}$. This topology is first-countable but it is not Hausdorff, hence not metrizable.